# How to complete scrape a web page with resources?

Tags: node.js, linux, web-scraping, wget, httrack

I want total scrape a web page with all resources (.css, .html, .favicon, ,js etc...)

Currently, I'm using this command to do that.

`wget -E -H -k -K -e robots=off -p https://example.com -P ./myDir`

However, on some pages, the downloaded folder has missing files.

For example, this is a website template and there's no .html file.

`wget -E -H -k -K -e robots=off -p https://nicepage.com/html-templates/preview/zero-waste-166766?device=desktop -P ./myDir`

Do you know any better way to scrape web pages? I'm using node.js so you can advise me of some node.js packages too.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can use cheero.js to scare files. You can then look for <link> tags and <script> tags, and parse the corresponding files, e.g: example.com/js/script.js, or example.com/css/dark-theme/mobile.css.

Comment: That would be a much more complicated way but I'll keep that in my mind.